# Can't retrieve data from a linked server (IBM i series win 7.1) on my local SQL Server (SSMS 2014 64 bit) -- but yes from a SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

We have one workstation (win 7 Pro) with SQL Server 2014 (64 bit) which can create and access data from a linked IBM iSeries server. This particular workstation also has SQL  Server 2008 R2 loaded on it. My workstation only has SSMS 2014 64 bit (and the SQL Server Express that comes with Visual Studio 2012 which I also have loaded on my workstation (win 7 Pro 64 bit)), and I cannot retrieve data from a query from the same linked server.

However, using the same ODBC DNS I created for this linked server in MS Access (2007) I can retrieve/see the data in the tables from this IBM i series server/database -- in MS Access.

With the following script, I am able to create a linked server in SSMS 2014 64 bit and can actually expand the respective linked server Icon and see my desired IBM i series database (T9S) and even see the listing of all the tables, but when I run a query against any of the tables I get this error message:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "CWMPDTA" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
>   Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 7
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "CWMPDTA".

Code:

```
--this is the script I am using to create the linked server in SSMS 2014:
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
    @server = N'CWMPDTA',
    @srvproduct=N'CWMPDTA',
    @provider=N'MSDASQL',
    @datasrc=N'iSeries2',
    @provstr=N'Provider=IBMDA400.DataSource.1;Password=myPwrd;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myID;Data Source=10.0.0.51;Initial Catalog=T9S',
    @catalog=N'T9S'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
    @rmtsrvname=N'CWMPDTA',
    @useself=N'False',
    @locallogin=NULL,
    @rmtuser=N'myID',
    @rmtpassword='myPwrd'
```

Basically, I copied this script from the Sql Server 2005 linked server (32 bit). The IBM i series ODBC driver (I named the DSN 'iSeries2') is 32 bit, and I created the DSN in the 64bit ODBC manager (yes, I also created a DSN in the 32 bit ODBC manager with the same IBM driver but that DSN wouldn't even create a linked server in SSMS 2014 on my workstation).  I am thinking this may be a 32 bit / 64 bit mismatch issue ?

I have gone to a few IBM sites and experimented with different provider strings, parameters, ..., but the script above is the only which will at least create a linked server. I just can't reach the data, even though I can see the tables in SSMS (2014 64 bit).  Has anyone else had this problem?  I would be very grateful if someone had a script (someone from IBM maybe?) that could create a linked server to SSMS 2014 (64 bit) where I could reach the data.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for my problem -- it is in the DSN configuration.  I went back to the ODBC manager -- the DSN must be create in the System DSN section, then ... in the Performance tab I "Unchecked" the

'Enable pre-fetch of data for queries'.

option.  I then removed the linked server and relinked it with the same script as above.  Now I can query the tables in the linked server from SSMS 2014.